# print log file between two date and time pattern in perl

Tags: perl, parsing, date, logging

perl guru's

I got a question, I need to print the log file between two date range, that includes times as well.

for instance

```
log file btw (Current date & time and 1 week ago) or
log file btw (Current date & time and 1 month ago)
```

this is how my log file look.

```
02/12/15 13:05 some text here
02/11/15 12:05 some text here
02/10/15 10:05 some text here
02/09/15 09:05 some text here
02/08/15 08:05 some text here
02/07/15 01:05 some text here
--
-
-o/p truncated
-
01/29/15 13:05 some text here
01/29/15 12:05 some text here
01/29/15 10:05 some text here
01/29/15 09:05 some text here
01/29/15 08:05 some text here
01/29/15 01:05 some text here
```

Comment: set up two variables ($D1 = `date +%m/%d/%y" " %k:%M`, $D2 = `date -d "1 week ago" "+%m/%d%y %k:%M"`) and assigned current date time and 1 week or 1 month ago date time. Created a search pattern for those dates and used sed to print reading the log file.

Answer (score 1):

So, to accomplish this what you need is:

[`Time::Piece`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Time-Piece-1.29/Piece.pm) - which is a core module that lets you extract the numeric value of the respective dates.

In particular - `Time::Piece` has `strptime` which converts formatted time to a comparable value.

E.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ( $date, $time ) = split;
    my $t = Time::Piece->strptime( "$date $time", "%m/%d/%y %H:%M" );
    print $t, "\n";
}   

__DATA__
01/29/15 13:05 some text here
01/29/15 12:05 some text here
01/29/15 10:05 some text here
01/29/15 09:05 some text here
01/29/15 08:05 some text here
01/29/15 01:05 some text here
```

You can then use `$t` in comparisons, in order to figure out relative timing. (It's a special value, such that if you compare it numerically, it works as 'epoch' time.

E.g.:

```
my $one_week_ago = time() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60; 
if ( $t < $one_week_ago ) { #do something };
```

Comment: I am getting the below errors, appears I got to install cpan binaries/modules on my redhat 6 linux server, "Can't locate Time/Piece.pm in @INC (@INC contains". Plus I am getting below error in my Mac(10.10.2) laptop "Error parsing time at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Timepiece.pm line"                                                                            thanks

Comment: That's very strange. `Time::Piece` is a core module as of perl 5.9.5, so no installation should be needed.